# Django Timezone Support Outside of Templates

Tags: django, timezone, django-timezone

Django's timezone-aware output apparently [only applies when rendering a template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zone-aware-output-in-templates). Is there a way to get that same auto-conversion to the currently active timezone for responses returning CSV or JSON?

Comment: Are you looking for a django setting?  Or some python specific code?  Perhaps try using pytz?

Comment: No, I'm looking to get the same auto-conversion behavior you see in a template when I send a CSV or JSON response to a user.

Comment: I don't believe there is any auto-conversion outside of templates... you will have to do it manually.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've found. Any idea where the logic that runs on templates happens? Obviously I can render the CSV and JSON via a template, but that stinks.

Comment: Got exactly the same issue here,  thanks for asking. Too bad that its not supported, especially with the modern dynamic / javascript applications nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the underlying function called to convert datetimes in templates is `django.utils.timezone.template_localtime()`. Right next to it in the source is another utility function, `localtime`, which looks like:

```
def localtime(value, timezone=None):
    """
    Converts an aware datetime.datetime to local time.

    Local time is defined by the current time zone, unless another time zone
    is specified.
    """
    ...
```

So perhaps the following would work:

```
from django.utils.timezone import localtime, get_current_timezone

...

print localtime(obj.date_created, user.get_profile().timezone or get_current_timezone())
```